# import dataframe from dict without index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to generate a dataframe from a dict but I want to set the names of the columns. So, I Want a dataframe with `index = [1,2,3,4]`, `Column 1 = [keys of the dict]`, `Column 2 = [values of the dict]`
I put what I was trying to do just in case, but it works for only one column

```
a = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stdic, orient='index', columns=['Col 1'])
```

Input dictionary is:

```py
{key1: value1, key2: value2, ...}
```

Expected dataframe:

```
index Column 1    Column 2
1         key1      value1
2         key2      value2
```

Comment: can you post the sample input and expected output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list(d.values()), 'col2': list(d.keys())})
print(df)
```

outputs

```
   col1 col2
0     1    a
1     2    b
2     3    c
3     4    d
```

Comment: your answer should use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`. read the question carefully

Comment: @deadshot "generate a dataframe from a dict" != "use the from_dict method". The only reference to "from_dict" in the question is the code OP used.

Comment: If you really wants to use `from_dict`, use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').reset_index()`, but you have to rename the columns later.